# Creating PDF with asp Table using ABCPDF9 Gecko

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, abcpdf9

I have a aspx page that has an asp table which is then dynamically added to on page load using VB. This page needs to be turned into a PDF. We have used ABCPDF Gecko function which works fine apart from the fact that the tables are not displaying. Everything else on the page displays just not the tables.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else stuck the issue was due to the order of the rendering and post backs. The tables were not being rendered before the PDF Gecko function was called. Therefore the tables were blank.